AH01797, access_compat:error cannot find root cause
No matter where I set my "Require all granted" block in my httpd conf, I keep running into these errors:
[Thu May 30 10:55:16.510272 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076428] [client 10.192.157.118:62319] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/static/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css
[Thu May 30 10:55:16.511078 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076428] [client 10.192.157.118:62319] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/static/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css
[Thu May 30 10:55:16.511257 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076425] [client 10.192.157.118:62322] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/static/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css
[Thu May 30 10:55:16.511815 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076424] [client 10.192.157.118:62317] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/static/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css
[Thu May 30 10:55:16.513309 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076425] [client 10.192.157.118:62322] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/static/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css
[Thu May 30 10:55:16.514069 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076424] [client 10.192.157.118:62317] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/static/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css
[Thu May 30 10:55:17.583141 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076424] [client 10.192.157.118:62317] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/composer?showTarget=infra.vmware.vm.aadprddb02.company.com.cpu_usage_average&showTarget=infra.vmware.vm.aadprddb02.company.com.cpu_usage_average&width=586&height=308&target=infra.vmware.vm.aadprddb02.company.com.cpu_usage_average
[Thu May 30 10:55:17.583900 2024] [access_compat:error] [pid 1076424] [client 10.192.157.118:62317] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi, referer: https://graphite.company.com/composer?showTarget=infra.vmware.vm.aadprddb02.company.com.cpu_usage_average&showTarget=infra.vmware.vm.aadprddb02.company.com.cpu_usage_average&width=586&height=308&target=infra.vmware.vm.aadprddb02.company.com.cpu_usage_average

Here's my config:
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName graphite.company.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/app/graphite/webapp"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /app/graphite/webapp

  <Directory "/app/graphite/webapp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_error_log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_access_log" "mainserver"

  ## Server aliases
  ServerAlias ssl-graphite-web
  ServerAlias graphite.company.com

  ## SetEnv/SetEnvIf for environment variables
  SetEnv HTTPS On

  ## SSL directives
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      "/etc/ssl/certs/comapny.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/etc/ssl/certs/company.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/ssl/certs/compant.csr"
  SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  SSLCipherSuite          ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!aNULL:!SHA1

  ## Custom fragment
  Alias /media/ "/app/graphite/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"

ErrorLog /app/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
CustomLog /app/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

#WSGIScriptAlias / /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi
#WSGIImportScript /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=%{GLOBAL} application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory "/app/graphite/conf/">
  Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias / /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi
WSGIImportScript /app/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=%{GLOBAL} application-group=%{GLOBAL}
<Directory /app/graphite/static/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Location "/content/">
  Require all granted
</Location>
<Location "/media/">
  Require all granted
</Location>
<Location "/">
  Require all granted
</Location>

</VirtualHost>

Each directory has 0644 permissions and when troubleshooting, 777. I've been through selinux and even turned off filtering with semodule -DB to catch every possible error and I'm still seeing this. What permissions am I missing?

If you are not using Order,Allow,Deny,Satisfy deprecated directives, directly unload mod_access_compat. Also when using Location, you should define them in order of most global path first, otherwise you are overriding the latest one with the first ones you define.

Also, directories should have at most 755 not 644, while files should have at most 644. I would also try setting ¨allowoverride none" in documentroot directory.

May you also share your apache2.conf file? And more specifically the blocks related to allowed  "filetypes"

Hello @DanielFerradal, there's another module in the config that's using mod_access_compat. I set allowoverride none in the docroot directory. But I'm still seeing these errors.

Hello @petitradisgris. I'm on a red hat setup. So there isn't a htaccess file by default either.

@itinneed2022_1 well, the errors should say which file and line and the directive that is being used and where. I think you should check the errors.

@DanielFerradal The error's I'm seeing are the ones I posted. Is there a log level for apache that would specify the lines?

Check the permissions on the script and documentroot, also try setting AllowOverrride none. But I would insist in unloading mod_access_compat.

which version of httpd was this?

apache (httpd) 2.4
